# How to mock InputStream and ByteString

Tags: java, jmockit

I have a method like this

```
private byte[] getInternalMDPayload(String metaDataDirString)
{

    byte[] data = new byte[16384];

    try
    {
        final InputStream internalMetadataInputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader()
                .getResourceAsStream(metaDataDirString);        
        data = ByteStreams.toByteArray(internalMetadataInputStream);
        byteString = ByteString.copyFrom(data);

    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        dl.debug("Error occurred while loading the metadata file" + metaDataDirString);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to mock these objects?

Currently i am using `@Mocked final Process mockProcess` to mock the input stream couldn't able to find out how to mock `ByteString` and `byte[]`.

Comment: Which mocking framework you are using?

Comment: It sounds to me like it's `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream` that you're really trying to fake out. You don't need to mock the values themselves - it's trivial to use a `ByteArrayInputStream` as the input stream, at which point the rest falls out easily.

Comment: i am using jmockit framework.

Comment: thanks for the reply Jon . Could you give me some input how could i use ByteArrayInputStream as the InputStream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with this:

```
Mockito
    .when(ByteString.copyFrom(Mockito.<byte[]>any()))
    .thenReturn(ByteString.copyFromUtf8("byteString was mocked"));
```

Comment: it seems like i couldn't able to use Mockito . As i am using jmockit for this.

Comment: Please, add a tag for that framework to the question then.